# Terraform deploy Cognito Pool. "Invitation message" is always reset to default

Tags: terraform, amazon-cognito, pool

I have a code in Terraform which reads a list and makes a Cognito pool for each element. If there's a pool with the current name the pool is kept as is. **This works fine for me**. 
Generally speaking, if pool exists and a parameter for that pool is defined in Terraform code, that setting is reset in the existing pool accordingly, and kept as I see it in console if not. **This works fine for me too**. 
So if in Terraform I define, for instance, `password_policy` element the new rules are applied, if not existing rules are kept. Same successfully happens with `verification_message_template`.
**The problem is**: No matter if I define `invite_message_template` or not. In all cases the "invitation message" I see in console is reset to default.
Is this the expected behavior? Docs are not shedding light on it. Is there any way to keep the template for invitation as is in console?

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "multitenantpools" {
  for_each = {for i, v in local.tenants_list_nonsensitive:  i => v}
    name = "pool-${each.value.tenant}-${var.env}"

    deletion_protection = "ACTIVE"
    username_attributes = ["email"]
    auto_verified_attributes = ["email"]

    # password_policy {
    #   minimum_length = 8
    #   require_numbers = true
    #   require_uppercase = true
    #   require_lowercase = true
    # }

    # verification_message_template {
    #   default_email_option = "CONFIRM_WITH_CODE"
    #   email_subject = "Account Confirmation"
    #   email_message = "Your confirmation code is {####}"
    # }

    admin_create_user_config {
      allow_admin_create_user_only = true
    }

    schema {
      attribute_data_type      = "String"
      developer_only_attribute = false
      mutable                  = true
      name                     = "email"
      required                 = true

      string_attribute_constraints {
        min_length = 1
        max_length = 256
      }
    }

    tags = {
      #Name  = "${local.pool_prefix}_${each.value.tenant}_${var.env}"
      domain = "${each.value.domain}" # trick to inject custom info for Client resource
      tenant = "${each.value.tenant}" # trick to inject custom info for Client resource
    }

}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know `invite_message_template` is indeed included in `admin_create_user_config` so as I was setting `admin_create_user_config` I was also in a hidden way setting `invite_message_template`.
I found that `ignore_changes` prevents explicitly any changes.
So finally setting this kept my template untouched on console:

```
lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [
        password_policy,
        verification_message_template,
        admin_create_user_config, # includes invite_message_template
      ]
    }
```